# Is it better to reuse or to create an Analyzer, IndexSearcher, IndexWriter in every call?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I am a Lucene.net novice and trying to adapt the [search code from here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms) which essentially creates a new `Analyzer`, `IndexSearcher` and `IndexWriter` objects in every method and only the FSDirectory object is being reused.

**Question:** Is there a recommended best practice here for reusing these objects?

Previous results for Lucene.Net optimization are from years ago, and from personal experience the Lucene.Net library has changed: downloading examples and compiling them with 3.0.3 does not work without changing the code.

Comment: I would advise against the example code on the CodeProject link, as their 'best practices' have caused [problems in previous cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013032/why-is-lucene-net-indexer-throwing-a-system-io-ioexception-was-unhandled).

Answer (score 2):

How about [BestPractices](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/BestPractices), from the official wiki?

Comment: that's java-lucene docs, per the guys on the lucene java list, that's not the right place for .net version

Comment: Your question is also tagged `lucene`, not only `lucene.net`. Even so these best practices apply to all Lucene implementations. Did you actually read them?

Answer (score 2):

In our project, we reuse the `Analyzer` and inject it with a pre-defined `Version` to the `IndexWriter` and the `IndexReader`. It is recommended that the `Analyzer` be the same when indexing and when searching, so at least the pattern applies for it.

Since, the last two are wrappers for actual Lucene index access, you will need to instantiate an index stream every time you use them, and it would make little sense to reuse them as they will block concurrent calls (both `read`s and `write`s).

There are some 'best practices' and patterns in [this project](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2010/02/26/lucene.net-is-powering-subtext-2.5-search.aspx) that you can take advantage on.